# How can I implement a file browser in iOS

Tags: ios, button, onclick, file-browser

I want to open a file browser when I click a button in my application. For example if we want to send an email, we will attach a file by clicking attach file button. Like wise in iOS
if I click a button, a file browser should open and it should be possible to open a file with the ending pdf.

Comment: whenever click on button the file path is open in Browse

Comment: Button click show file browse option

Comment: In English questions end with an question mark. Search for this sign `?` on your keyboard.

Comment: ok button Click file browse Open?

Comment: we need to write code for that ?

Comment: Sorry but this is not enough information to help you. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask how to ask questions here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9462/discussion-between-venkat-and-dasdom)

Comment: i want to open a file browser when i click a button in my application.For example if we want to send an email,we will attach a file by clicking attach file button.Like wise in ios,if i click a button,a file browser should open and if i select a file with an extension of .pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a file browser and select a .pdf file in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922755/how-to-open-a-file-browser-and-select-a-pdf-file-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Your app can only act in it's sandbox or access files which are meant to be shared (like photos or contacts).