# Controller for implementing a file browser in iOS

Tags: ios, controller, file-browser

What Controller to be used for opening a file browser in iOS? Additionally, how do I set the path of an sd card in my application for reading the files which are stored in iPhone?

Comment: [Related.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922755/how-to-open-a-file-browser-and-select-a-pdf-file-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

There is one project that is just pure genius in my opinion, and it is called Accordion (with the beta of Accordion 2 included in the package as well).  It works like the arrow-drop-down option in the finder:

Source: https://github.com/nacho4d/Accordion

Comment: Is it a third party tool or a feature of Apple ios?

Comment: Third party, but I can vouch for it.  As for the SD card, I don't believe that iOS supports mounting external file systems onto your application bundle (excluding the Photos.app).